# cannot run angular node --version

Tags: node.js, angular-cli

https://angular.io/guide/setup-local#create-a-workspace-and-initial-application

node version  v12.20

npm version   v6.14.8

Already installed -  npm install -g @angular-devkit/core --save-dev

i followed the steps to create a angular app but below error comes

ng new my-app

(node:9292) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module '@angula
r-devkit/core'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\utilities
  config.js
- C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\init.j
  s

Comment: You want to run `npm install -g @angular/cli` to install the CLI, not `npm install -g @angular-devkit/core`.

Comment: tried also npm install -g @angular/cli but not works...i have cleared cache and deleted node_modules...everything done but error not solved

Comment: Think about updating to a newer version of node and try again.